# What is the limit on the number of entities in case of batch get/ save in objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, objectify

Objectify supports batch get of entities by using:

```
ofy().load().type(TestEntity.class).ids(testIdList).now();
```

and batch save by using:

```
ofy().save().entities(testEntityList).now();
```

My question is what is the limit on the number of entities that we can get or save using this approach?

Is there any limit specified by objectify/ datastore
Also even if there is no limit specified by objectify or datastore, I suppose there would be practical limit due to the 60 second timeout for each request in app engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not in a transaction, the only limits should be the 60s request deadline and the amount of RAM the entities occupy (F1 instances are rather tight).

Answer (score 0):

The limit is set on Entity size:

> - **Maximum size for an entity**  1,048,572 bytes (1 MiB - 4 bytes)

And Entity Groups:

> - **Maximum number of entity groups that can be accessed in a transaction**  25
> - **Maximum write rate to an entity group**            1 per sec

See the list of [limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) in the Google Cloud Datastore docs.

The [Objectify wiki](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#load-and-transactions) refers to these limits as well:

> **@Load and Transactions**
>
> The datastore limits you to 25 entity groups in a single
>   transaction....